# USB device not recognized for printer

Tags: windows-xp, usb, printer

I am trying to install a Canon MF4370dn printer on to a fairly old Dell desktop. I can run the install disks just fine with no errors popping up. I restart the computer and connect the USB cable. I keep getting the USB device is not recognized balloon.

Here is what I have tried:

- tested all USB ports with a different printer, and the keyboard/mouse and they work
- tested the cable on a different printer and it works
- uninstalled and reinstalled the printer drivers (both from the installation disk and from the website)
- uninstalled and reinstalled the USB drivers
- unplugging the computer and printer and waiting for 20 minutes before plugging them back in again

all to no avail.

As of right now, I am talking to canon via email, but they are not helping much. Unfortunately this printer can't be moved since it is also the fax, scanner and has to be in the vicinity of the telephone line.

The computer is running Windows XP SP3 with all updates/patches installed. I really need to get this fixed. If more information is needed  please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Is the Canon printer new or was it connected to another computer before? Looks like you have tested the USB ports on the computer. Have you connected the Canon printer to another computer to test the USB port on the printer is working? What is the OS on the old Dell Desktop